# Remove default rectangular border of edittext when opened in dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, android-dialog

How can i remove the default rectangular border of `EditText` when opened in dialog?
I tried by setting background to null but it didn't worked.That  rectangular border only appears with `EditText` when I use it in dialog.

Here is the **XML** layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_whitedialog"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
...
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@null" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp48"
             android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp12"
            android:textColor="@color/numbertextcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp16" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the **Java** code:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext, R.style.DialogSlideAnim);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_item);
dialog.show();
```

[image]

Comment: To remove border in EditText please provide background drawable in EditText. Plus TextInputEditText with TextInputLayout as mentioned in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

Comment: try android:background="@null" in your edittext

Comment: @kgandroid already tried.. not working

Comment: @Ramit replacing EditText with TextInputEditText and setting android:background="@android:color/transparent" worked for me..can u please post it as answer?

Comment: @AndroidLearner I added answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove border in EditText please provide background drawable in EditText. Plus TextInputEditText with TextInputLayout as mentioned in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I have use your code to generate a dialog. This is what i got.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@color/white"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="@string/new_password"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can your show some screenshot, how you want it to be? before and after

Comment: Image added in question.i want it to appear as it appears normally (if not used in dialog)without that rectangular background

Comment: uploaded screenshot of my code. if there is no transparent background, there will have a line under that field

Comment: Are u using this code for a dialog?.. bcoz this issue only happens with dialig

Comment: only in dialog? oh...that's weird. no. mine running on fragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121317/discussion-between-kggoh-and-android-learner).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background of Edit Text to transparent

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Hello"
    android:background="#00000000" />
```